# What postgresql client version should I build against, if server is 8.x?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I'm planning updates to a system that is currently running with 8.x server on Windows, 8.x client on Windows, and 8.x client on Linux.  Obviously that seems like a bad choice of platform in a mixed environment, but the Linux machine has no persistent writable storage (as an anti-rootkit measure).  I'm concerned with compatibility between versions right now.

Can a linux postgresql 9.0.x client connect to a Windows 8.x server?  The server is using some third-party binary extensions, so upgrading it is a more involved task and will be done later.

If combining a 9.0.x client and 8.x server is discouraged, would latest 8.x clients be able to continue to connect if I did upgrade the server first?

META: What tag is appropriate for backward-compatibility questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about clients in general, postgresql's client communication protocol is stable and hasn't changed since postgresql 7.4 (protocol version 3.0) according to [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/protocol.html).  Thus, any client can communicate with any server since then.  Additionally, libpq can apparently connect to protocol 2.0 [servers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/libpq-status.html#LIBPQ-PQPROTOCOLVERSION).

If you're talking about the `psql` commandline client, it can connect to old servers (it uses libpq) but the backslash commands (such as `\d tablename`) query the database's `pg_catalog` tables to return the information you're looking for.  According to [psql's documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-psql.html#AEN75717), the client knows how to execute the `\d` commands on the previous versions of the database but other commands may or may not work if the catalog schema they use has changed.  (The `\d` commands are pretty much *all of them* so you shouldn't have any problems.)

As an aside, you can use `\set ECHO_HIDDEN` to see what exactly psql is doing when you use the backslash commands. `\unset ECHO_HIDDEN` to return the backslash commands to normal.

Comment: clients in general, the actual Linux client used is Perl `DBD::Pg`.